# Incompatible pointer type warning whit in self referencied structs, trying to implement a hash table

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to implement a hash table with pointers to a double-linked list that stores the information in C language. The problem is that i keep getting warnings from the compiler that I don't understand why. The warnings are all "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type "

Here are my structs:

```
typedef struct stru_contacto_list{
char *nome;
char *email;
char *telefone;
struct stru_contacto_list *prev, *next;
}contacto_list;




typedef struct stru_contacto{
contacto_list *info;
struct stru_contact *next_hash;
}contacto_hash;

typedef struct{
contacto_hash **val;
}hash_tableC;
```

Here is some code for you to understand better what is hapening:

Initializing the hash table

```
void initContactos(hash_tableC *c){
    int i;
    c->val = 
       (contacto_hash**)malloc(sizeof(contacto_hash)*DEFAULTSIZE);
    for(i = 0; i < DEFAULTSIZE; i++){
        c->val[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Here's some code from where I get the warnings, here im am trying to add a 'contact_hash' to the hash table by putting it in the head of the linked list associated to the index in the hash_table.

```
void addContact(){

    int index, flag;

    contacto_hash *novo = 
                    (contacto_hash*)malloc(sizeof(contacto_hash));

    contacto_list *novoL = 
                    (contacto_list*)malloc(sizeof(contacto_list));


    flag = addContactToList(novoL);

    if (flag){
        free(novo);
        return;
    }

    novo->info = novoL;
    novo->next_hash = NULL;

    index = hashing(novoL->nome);

    if (contactos->val[index] != NULL)
        novo->next_hash =  contactos->val[index]; /* THE WARNING*/
    contactos->val[index] = novo;

}
```

Some other small piece of code where I get the same "warning : assignment from incompatible pointer type " :

```
contacto_hash* find(char *nome, int indice){
    /*Returns the previous contact_hash i want to find*/

    contacto_hash *atual, *prev;

    if (contactos->val[indice] == NULL)
        return NULL;

    atual = contactos->val[indice];
    prev = atual;

    while (atual != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(atual->info->nome, nome) == 0){
            return prev;
        }
        prev = atual;
        atual = atual->next_hash; /* THE WARNING */
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The warning from the compiler is "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: because `atual` is of type `struct stru_contacto` but  `next_hash` is of type `struct stru_contact`

Comment: And compiler should give error not warning.

Comment: OMG, of course. I feel so embaressed now, thanks a lot for your help!